# How accurate can a point in space be determined by the likes of the ICRF?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mathematics, coordinates

How accurately could a 3D point in open space (i.e. not on an object), say at an elevation of 30,000m above sea level, be located or modelled using the likes of the [International Celestial Reference Frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Celestial_Reference_Frame) (ICRF)?

Comment: Interesting question! You have the accuracy of Earth's center of mass position in ICRF plus all the uncertainties in defining a point relative to it.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you're talking about [Earth Orientation Parameters](https://www.iers.org/IERS/EN/Science/EarthRotation/EOP.html) which give the Earth's polar and rotational position (ie, the XYZ system formed by the Earth's north pole, equator, and prime meridian) with great accuracy. The parameters vary enough that, for maximal accuracy, they have to be updated every 2 weeks or so. There are longer-term estimates, but they are less accurate.